# How to unit test ServletResponse Java

Tags: java, servlets, junit, mockito, ioexception

Here is my code for servlet:

```
String foo = "foo";
Foo foo = Foofactory.getfoos(foo);
String locationURI;
String redirectURI = "http://" + request.getServerName() + ":" +request.getServerPort() + "/foo";
locationURI = foo.getRequestBuilder(redirectURI);
response.sendRedirect(locationURI);
```

Here I want to test the `IOException` for `response.sendRedirect(locationURI);`

I cannot use Mockito when feature as it shows void method cannot be used.

```
@Test(expected = IOException.class)
public void testService_CheckIOException() throws ServletException,     IOException {
    when(mockFoofactory.getfoos(Matchers.eq("foo"))).thenReturn(mockfoo);
    when(mockRequest.getServerName()).thenReturn("serverName");
    when(mockRequest.getServerPort()).thenReturn(80);
    when(mockfoo.getRequestBuilder(Matchers.eq("http://serverName:80foo")))
        .thenReturn("locationURI");
    Servlet.service(mockRequest, mockResponse);
    //This line doesn't work in mockito
    when(mockResponse).sendRedirect("locationURI")).thenThrow(IOException.class);
```

Is there anyway I can throw `IOException` and test for send redirect? I want to test the `IOException` and `IllegalStateException` that `sendRedirect` method throws.

Comment: You can do something like: `doThrow(IOException.class).when(mockResponse).sendRedirect("locationURI");`. Take a look at the [documentation](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Mockito` with `void` methods.

```
doNothing().when(mock).voidMethod();
```

In the same way you can use `doThrow(new IOException())`

Comment: I used this but it doesn't throw IOException. The expected IOException shows error

Comment: Make sure that in you test `.sendRedirect("locationURI")` is called. I rather suggest to mock in this way `doThrow(IOException.class).when(mockResponse).sendRedirect(anyString());` and use `verify` to check passed argument.

Comment: Worked....Awesome..Thank you so much